# OWA webpart view

Tags: 2010, web-part, outlook, 2003

I added OWA webpart in 2010 but I want the view to look like following like we had in SP 2003. How is it possible as there are no configuration for it in web-part? Please suggest.

2003 look
[image]

2010 look

[image: https://cdn2.content.compendiumblog.com/uploads/user/217a210f-f661-40cf-843a-a67a8c04fed9/8b9ae761-7320-4444-af11-566e8d46dad6/Image/6cd45874c39d6889c96cff101d790bf1/5.png]

Comment: I have very similar situation. I hope someone jumps in and provide a solution to this issue.